# If a subgroup $H$ has index $n$ in $G$ does that mean that $H$ has n conjugacy classes when partitioned by elements of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

If a subgroup $H$ has index $n$ in $G$ does that mean that $H$ has $n$ conjugacy classes when partitioned by elements of $G$?

I think this is probably a weird question, but I just think the index of $H$ being $n$ means that the elements of $G$ partition something like a collection of cosets: $\{g_1H,......,g_nH\}$, is this set identical to  $\{g_1Hg_1^{-1},......,g_nHg_n^{-1}\}$??

Thanks!

Comment: It that was true, then any subgroup in an *abelian* group would always have index equal to its cardinality...and this is certainly not true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asserting that $H$ has index $n$ in $G$ is the same thing as asserting that the set $\{gH\mid g\in G\}$ has $n$ elements. In other wrods, there are $n$ elements $g_1,\ldots,g_n\in G$ such that$$\{gH\mid g\in G\}=\{g_1H,\ldots,g_nH\}.$$But, in general, this set is *not* $\{g_1H{g_1}^{-1},\ldots,g_nH{g_n}^{-1}\}$. If $H$ is a *normal* subgroup of $G$, then$$\{g_1H{g_1}^{-1},\ldots,g_nH{g_n}^{-1}\}=\{H\},$$which consists of a single element.

Comment: Right, so when $G$ acts by conjugation on a subgroup $H$ of index $n$, it's not acting on the conjugacy classes of $H$, it's acting on a set of cosets as you described above. Okay, thanks man that really helps!!!